Build fails on `plugin needed to handle lto object` when trying to combine two libraries with `dot_a_linkage=true`
The project structure is the following:
HID-Project Library -\
                      >---> Custom Library 2 -> project.ino
Custom Library 1 ----/

Both HID-Project Library and Custom Library 1 have dot_a_linkage=true.
When I try to build the project it fails on lto plugin.
Consumer.cpp.o: plugin needed to handle lto object

Command line building the project (I use Arduino IDE 2.3.3 on Windows) is the following:
"C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc"
-Wall
-Wextra
-Os
-g
-flto
-fuse-linker-plugin
-Wl,--gc-sections
-mmcu=atmega32u4
-o
"C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\D15174364F07792C498DDA13DC5F9CF7/volume_control_and_pc_busy_simulator.ino.elf"
"C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\D15174364F07792C498DDA13DC5F9CF7\\sketch\\volume_control_and_pc_busy_simulator.ino.cpp.o"
"C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\D15174364F07792C498DDA13DC5F9CF7\\libraries\\HID-Project\\HID-Project.a"
"C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\D15174364F07792C498DDA13DC5F9CF7\\libraries\\HID\\HID.cpp.o"
"C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\D15174364F07792C498DDA13DC5F9CF7\\libraries\\support_library\\support_library.a"
"C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\D15174364F07792C498DDA13DC5F9CF7\\libraries\\peripherals_library\\peripherals_library.a"
"C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\D15174364F07792C498DDA13DC5F9CF7/..\\..\\cores\\arduino_avr_micro_bdb0ea67b0fdabd05f48f42cab13e7fd\\core.a"
"-LC:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\D15174364F07792C498DDA13DC5F9CF7"
-lm

As soon as I comment out dot_a_linkage=true build succeeds.
Because my custom library depends on 3rd party library (HID-Project) I'd want to be able to fix build without changing it's properties.

and if you have dot_a_linkage only in the HID library?

@Juraj the same. Moreover I have an older version of the same project where all the code is in ino file and it stops working if dot_a_linkage is commented out in HID-Project.

yes the HID-project library doesn't work without dot_a_linkage because all global instances for different USB devices collide if they are all linked. with dot_a_linkage the linker only picks used instances from the .a file.

@Juraj Interesting fact. I simplified the hierarchy a bit. Now I have only one library but it still depends on HID-Project. Still having the same issue. As far as I understand -fuse-linker-plugin should be resolving it, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

maybe something can be changed in Consumer.cpp
